# Should [insert build here] questions be encouraged?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do we do about character build questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/what-do-we-do-about-character-build-questions)

There's been a few questions asking about specific builds for Skyrim.  [Example 1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39836/would-an-illusion-archery-build-work-do-i-need-magicka-for-it) [Example 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39525/conjuration-archer-enchanting-or-alchemy-or-smithing)  How should these be handled?  Are they too localized to be useful?